# (Android) Launching file in an external app and catching an error from the external app

Tags: android, error-handling, android-intent, launching-application

I have an Android app that opens a file using an external application (audio, video files launch the default media player, etc.)

I need to be able to catch if there were any errors while launching the external application. For example, when I launch a .au file (audio) from my app and the media player app says "sorry, the player does not support this type of file" I would like to catch this exception somehow.

Is there a way for my app to detect that error? I tried using startActivityForResult and overriding onActivityResult, but external apps don't seem to return a data object or response code. Instead, both variables are null

Comment: regarding startActivityForResult, do you mean that you does not get any result at all or what?

Comment: I dont get any data back, or response codes; I was hoping i would see some data or a response code returned from an activity in the media player

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to detect errors from an external app. My app will have to rely on user input as to whether or not their file launched successfully